# Show Complex Toast From BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, user-interface, dalvik, toast

I wonder if someone can help me. I'm trying to display a toast element when an SMS is received. This toast should contain a layout which has an image (SMS Icon) and 2 textviews (sender, message)

If I call the following method from an activity, it works as expected...

```
public void showToast(Context context, String name, String message) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_sms,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_sms_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastsms_text);
    text.setText(message);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

However, if I try to call the same code in the same way from my SMSReceiver, I get:

```
The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type SmsReceiver
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type SmsReceiver
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type SmsReceiver
```

Can someone please advise how I can do tihs from an intent. I assume the issue is somehow related to cross-threading however, I'm unsure how to proceed. I've seen a couple of examples online but they seem to either use deprecated code or only display simple text

Can someone please point me in the correct direction

Many thanks

Comment: Any reason/constructive criticism for the downvote?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use LayoutInflater.from(context) to get your LayoutInflater. Like this:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customToast, null);
TextView sender = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sender);
TextView message = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.message);
```

Answer (score 7):

Your compile errors are because `BroadcastReceiver` does not inherit from `Context`. Use the `Context` that is passed into `onReceive()` (and get rid of `getApplicationContext()` -- just use the `Context` you are passed).

Now, this may *still* not work, as I am not sure if you can raise a `Toast` from a `BroadcastReceiver` in the first place, but this will at least get you past the compile errors.

Comment: Ok, I'm now doing new Toast(context) but it hasn't resolved th other 2 compile errors - getLayoutInflater and findViewById. How can I reference/instantiate these?

Comment: findViewById() only exists in Activity. Pass in null as your second parameter to the layout() call. To get a LayoutInflater, see the documentation for LayoutInflater in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

A toast can be created and displayed from an Activity or Service, not Broadcast receiver

Comment: No, a toast can be displayed from a broadcast receiver, it worked for me, so it is possible.