# Android toast.makeText context error

Tags: android, android-context

I am having trouble calling toast.Maketext inside of a location listener. The context is not available, what am I doing wrong?

```
private LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        // SMSReceiver.l = l;
        String s = "";
        s += "\tTime: " + l.getTime() + "\n";
        s += "\tLatitude:  " + l.getLatitude() + "°\n";
        s += "\tLongitude: " + l.getLongitude() + "°\n";
        s += "\tAccuracy:  " + l.getAccuracy() + " metres\n";
        s += "\tAltitude:  " + l.getAltitude() + " metres\n";
        s += "\tSpeed:  " + l.getSpeed() + " metres\n";

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (l.hasSpeed()) {
            mySpeed = l.getSpeed();
        }

        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "On Location Changed: (" + s + ")");
ERROR HERE-->       Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

Comment: Try this Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I tried that and I get:

**The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new LocationListener(){}**

Comment: I should note that this in **BroadcastReceiver** and not **Activity**

Comment: Hey try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618800/show-complex-toast-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: pass a instance of your activity and do like this **myactivity.getApplicationContext()**

Answer (score 7):

If this `LocationListener` declaration is inside an activity class (say: `MyActivity`), you should create the `Toast` as:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In case the `LocationListener` is declared in a contextless class, like in your case a `BroadcastReceiver`, you can pass the context to its constructor:

```
private final class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private MyLocationListener listener; 
    public MyReceiver(final Context context)
    {
        this.listener = new MyLocationListener(context);
    }

    private final class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        private Context context;
        public MyLocationListener(final Context context)
        {
            this.context = context; 
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            // ...
            Toast.makeText(context, "Toast message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // implement the rest of the methods
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Note that you have a context here, which you can use when receiving an broadcast message
    }
}
```

Comment: How come this answer got upvote, LocationListener in BroadcastReceiver and not in Activity

Comment: @RikudoPain please elaborate your concern, since it's not clear. What makes you think the anonymous instantiation of the LocationListener is not declared inside a contextful component (which being a common design choice)?

Comment: Please read his comment "I should note that this in BroadcastReceiver and not Activity" probably he forgot to edit the question. Since I have same problem with him

Comment: Without the full code it's hard to foresee how the op has structured the flow, but if both the `BroadcastReceiver` (or `LocationListener`) is in a separate class, and you really want to perform gui operations from it, you need to pass a context to its constructor to do so. I'll update my answer with a quick sample.

Comment: Correct, and need some changes in variable declaration in Activity too

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you use the context of the Activity class.If you are using this toast in an Activity, write, Classname.this in place of context

Answer (score 2):

Since context is not available,you can pass it in constructor