# Toast fails to show when within a AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context, android-toast

I have a simple application which sends an image (Base64 encoded) to a server, the server gets this data fine because the PHP script sends me an email with the Base64 Data attached. However, after the task gets completed the toast never shows. How do I take the Toast get shown after the data gets posted?

I think the issue is within the context.

http://pastie.org/2616524

**UPDATE**

I have updated the link, because i have since moved the upload logic into a different .java file.

Comment: instead of `getApplicationContext()` use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample look OK. If Activity, to which mContext variable belongs is currently active, it should show. Not in other case.

try this modification:

```
new UploadImage(ImageUploadActivity.this).execute(sentImage);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html
[Android toast.makeText context error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867274/android-toast-maketext-context-error)

**EDIT: WRONG TYPE DECLARATION OF AsyncTask**
your `AsyncTask` declaration looks like `class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

This means:

- is type of params to `doInBackground(String... arg)`
- is type of progress
- is type of result from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`

So change your `onPostExecute` declaration to this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

or change return type of `doInBackground` to `<Bitmap>` and change class declaration to: `class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: can you look at the edit please, i have moved the upload logic into a different file.

Comment: there's no problem even after modification, can you try replacing `this` with `ImageUploadActivity.this` ?

Comment: Nope, still nothing. Does my PHP script need to return anything? So far the script returns nothing.

Comment: Ok. I got it working. getApplicationContext() worked fine, however the issue was within the line `protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {`, I forgot that I eventually changed the passed data from a Bitmap object to a String object. This was not calling the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: @dotty next time add `@Override` before overriden methods... so if you do wrong method compiler(or IDE) will tell you about it

Comment: @dotty Oh, looks like you realized right solution, in same time :D