# How to make custom toast in OnReceive(under Broadcast) class?

Tags: java, android

I'M making application in android studio and we try to show up custom toast regularly. 
But since Broadcast don't have "View" , I can't use codes below.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bad0, (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_bad0));

Toast toast = new Toast(mcontext.getApplicationContext());

                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setView(layout);
                    toast.show();
```

//toast_layout_bad0 is the name of xml file we designed for toast.

I'm thinking of using interface but I'm not sure.
Is there some way that I can use custom toast in Broadcast?

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final String strId =  "my_channel_01";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("abc","Toast");
        Toast.makeText(context,"sdf",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//We want to change this simple toast to custom toast
}
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618800/show-complex-toast-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: you can create method to show your custom toast with message and context argument and call that method when you received your broadcast !

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

Alter the above line of text to the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bad0, 
              (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_bad0));
```

Alter the above line of text to the following:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bad0, null);
Toast toast = new Toast(context);

toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```